# Using a drop down menu for multiple Cryptocurrency line charts

Tags: plotly, dropdown, cryptocurrency, linegraph

I am pretty new to Python and working on a fun little project to chart numerous different cryptocurrencies based on their closing price for the day. I would like to have a drop down menu that allows me to select either one cryptocurrency to chart or multiple at the same time. What would be the best way to do this? Here is the code I have so far which successfully displays a line chart showing 25 different lines for 25 currencies.

```
`from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as po
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import re


#get crypto data from yahoo finance

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/cryptocurrencies?count=100&offset=0'

#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0
For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    col.append((name,[]))

for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    #T is our j'th row
    T=tr_elements[j]
    #i is the index of our column
    i=0
    #Iterate through each element of the row
    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content()
        #Check if row is empty
        if i>0:
        #Convert any numerical value to integers
            try:
                data=int(data)
            except:
                pass
        #Append the data to the empty list of the i'th column
        col[i][1].append(data)
        #Increment i for the next column
        i+=1

Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
crypto_df = df.set_index('Symbol')

CRYPTOS = []
CURRENCY = 'USD'

# create list of crypto symbols

for x in crypto_df.index:
    x = x.split('-')[0]
    CRYPTOS.append(x)


def getData(cryptocurrency):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    last_year_date = (now - timedelta(days=365)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    start = pd.to_datetime(last_year_date)
    end = pd.to_datetime(current_date)

    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(f'{cryptocurrency}-{CURRENCY}', start, end)

    return data

crypto_data = {crypto:getData(crypto) for crypto in CRYPTOS}

# crypto_data = dict()
# for crypto in CRYPTOS:
#     crypto_data[crypto] = getData(crypto)

fig = go.Figure()

    # Scatter
for idx, name in enumerate(crypto_data):
    fig = fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = crypto_data[name].index,
            y = crypto_data[name].Close,
            name = name,
        )
    )


fig.update_layout(
    title = 'Cryptocurrency Price Chart',
    xaxis_title = 'Date',
    yaxis_title = f'Closing price ({CURRENCY})',
    legend_title = 'Cryptocurrencies')


fig.update_yaxes(type='log', tickprefix='$')



po.plot(fig)`
```